# Log4Net Class Logger level per Appender-ref

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trying to separate out a Performance Logger into a separate log using Log4Net...

I setup my new Appender

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Logs\ServiceLayer.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="_yyyy.MM.dd.lo\g" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" /> -->
        <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %5level [%thread][%property{myclass.log.username}::%property{myclass.log.businessRequest}(%property{myclass.log.activityLogID})]  - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
<appender name="PerfFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Logs\Perf.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="_yyyy.MM.dd-HH-mm.lo\g" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="24" />
    <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" /> -->
        <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %5level [%thread][%property{myclass.log.username}::%property{myclass.log.businessRequest}(%property{myclass.log.activityLogID})]  - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

The perf appender is the new appender I added...

I also set up a BufferForwardingAppender

```
<appender name="MyDefaultAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender">
<bufferSize value="128" />
<lossy value="false" />
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN" />
</evaluator>
<appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
```

From there I set my Root

```
<root>
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="MyDefaultAppender" />
</root>
```

Once I had this setup, I get ERRORs logged to my rolling log file, however I want to capture some info level data into my perf file...

```
<logger name="MyNamespace.MyClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="PerfFile" />
</logger>
<logger name="MyNamespace.MyOtherClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="PerfFile" />
</logger>
<logger name="MyNamespace.MyThirdClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="PerfFile" />
</logger>
<logger name="MyNamespace.MyFinalClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="PerfFile" />
</logger>
```

I now get my Info and Warn in my Perf log but I also get my errors there too, is it possible to get my ERRORs in my main log and my info levels in my perf logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control what log events get into each file, Add [`LevelRangeFilters`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter.html) to your appenders:

```
<!-- log error and above - add to the RollingFile appender config -->
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="ERROR"/>
  <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
</filter>
```

and

```
<!-- log INFO and below - add to the PerfFile appender config -->
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
  <levelMax value="INFO"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: Is this possible todo for each individual class logger rather than the appender? I want all all the classes I don't specify to be able to log to info on the RollingFile...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't apply filters to loggers, which as you have seen only have the one level property, which "Defines the logging level for [the] logger. This logger will only accept event that are at this level or above."